# know when data has finished loading(promised) from Infinite scroll factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below Infinite-scroll factory i am using to get data from backend, is there any where to apply $promise to this method as in controller i need to know when data has finished loading .

**Factory :**

```
app.factory('Gallery', function($http) {
   var Gallery = function(media, album_type) {
        this.items = [];
        this.busy = false;
        this.next = '/upload/list/'+ media +'/?album='+album_type+'&page=1';
        this.end=false;
    };

    Gallery.prototype.nextPage = function() {
        if (this.busy) return;
        this.busy = true;
        if (this.next){
            var url = this.next;
        }
        else{
            this.end=true;
            this.busy = false;
            return
        }
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            var items = data.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                this.items.push(items[i]);
            }
            this.next=data.next;
            this.busy = false;
            if (!data.next)
                this.end=true;
            this.count=data.count;
        }.bind(this));
    };

    return Gallery;
});
```

**In Controller;**

```
   $scope.images = $scope.images || new ScrollGallery('image', 'CRP');
```

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough try adding more information about the code and your problem. It's really hard understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by adding  $q in ininite-service , $q returns promise method .which i can use to to check if http was success to failed .

**Infinite-service ::**

```
 app.factory('ScrollGallery', function($http,$q) {

    var Gallery = function(url) {
        this.items = [];
        this.busy = false;
        this.next = url;
        this.end = false;
        this.extra = {};

    };

    Gallery.prototype.nextPage = function() {
        var def = $q.defer();
        if (this.busy)
            return;
        this.busy = true;
        if (this.next) {
            var url = this.next;
        } else {
            this.end = true;
            this.busy = false;
            return;
        }
        $http.get(url).success( function(data) {

            var items = data.results;
            var extra = [];
            if ( typeof data.extra != 'undefined') {
                extra = data.extra;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                this.items.push(items[i]);
            }
            this.extra = extra;
            this.next = data.next;
            this.busy = false;
            if (!data.next)
                this.end = true;
            this.count = data.count;
              def.resolve(data);
        }.bind(this));
        return def.promise;
    };

    return Gallery;
});
```

**In controller ::**

```
$scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url] =new ScrollGallery($scope.slider_url_pass); 
        $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url].nextPage().then(function(albums) {

                $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url].items[$scope.img_no].active=true;

                console.log('albums returned to controller.');
            },
            function(data) {
                console.log('albums retrieval failed.');
            });
```